# Update a split table without retrieving the data

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1, code-first

I have a table and I splitted in 2 entities:

```
public class User
{
  [key]
  public byte ID{get;set;}
  ... 
  ...
  public virtual UserAddress{get;set;}
}
```

class UserAddress:

```
public class UserAddress
{
  [key]
  public byte ID{get;set;}
  public string Address{get;set;}
  ...
}
```

When I try to insert, it works perfectly. But I want to update the UserAddress without load the User data:

GenericDAO.cs

```
public abstract class GenericDAO<TEntity>: IGenericRepository<TEntity>  where TEntity : class
{

private ObjectContext _context;
private IObjectSet<TEntity> _objectSet;


public GenericDAO()
  : this(((IObjectContextAdapter)new MyContext()).ObjectContext)
{

}

public GenericDAO(ObjectContext context)
{
    _context = context;
    _objectSet = _context.CreateObjectSet<TEntity>();
}

public void Save(TEntity entity, System.Data.EntityState state)
{
  if(state == System.Data.EntityState.Added)
       _objectContext.AddObject(entity);
  else
       _objectContext.Attach(entity);

  _context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(entity).ChangeState(state);

  _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

As I say, When I Add the object, works. But when I try to update the object, I don't receive any error but my UserAddress is not updated.

Anybody can help me?

Thank you in advance

EDIT: The GenericDAO.cs is updated.

My MyContext.cs

```
public MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> User{get;set;}
    public DbSet<UserAddress> UserAddress {get;set}

    protected override OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
       modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UserConfiguration());
       modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UserAddressConfiguration());
    }
}
```

UserConfiguration.cs

```
public class UserConfiguration: EntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public UserConfiguration()
        : base()
    {
        HasKey(p => p.ID);
        Property(p => p.ID).HasColumnName("UserID").HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity).IsRequired();

        HasRequired(p => p.UserAddress).WithRequiredPrincipal();

        ToTable("User");

    }

}
```

UserAddressConfiguration.cs

```
public class UserAddressConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<UserAddress>
{
    public UserAddressConfiguration ()
        : base()
    {
        HasKey(p => p.ID);
        ToTable("User");
    }
}
```

ConcreteDAO.cs

```
public class ConcreteDAO<T> : GenericDAO<T> where T: class
{
}
```

And Inside my UserDAO.cs

```
public class UserDAO
{
     public static void Save(User user)
     {
        System.Data.EntityState state = System.Data.EntityState.Added;
        if (user.ID > 0)
            state = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;

        new ConcreteDAO<User>().Save(user, state);
     }
}
```

Comment: First: your code cant compile (property UserAddress in class User is missing a name; _objectContext in GenericDAO.cs is not declared, at least not in the code snippet you posted), so its probably not the code you tried. Can you fix please?
Second: how do you load the addresse to be updated? And how do you call the Save(...) method? What's in the parameters?

Comment: @okrumnow I updated my question to work. Do you need any more information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your UserDAO (and in the whole expectation that this generic approach will work). You are saving a user entity and setting its state but you didn't tell EF that address was modified as well. You must set correct state for each entity in object graph which makes generic approach quite difficult.

If you call `AddObject` EF will go through entity graph and mark all unknown entities as added automatically (you don't need to set the state for them) but when you call `Attach` EF will go through the entity graph and mark all unknown entities as unchanged. Because you have changed the state only for user the address is not updated to the database.